# vite proxy config on dotnet spa seem not working

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, vite

I want to create dotnet SPA account with react,
I found this on a [Blog](https://blog.codeinside.eu/2023/02/11/aspnet-core-react-with-vitejs/) is petty good

I try to follow it , and it's work
but right now I want to make proxy call in front end
Firstly, in dotnet, I create api controller
like below :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PublicDataController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("book")]
    public Book GetBook()
    {
        return new Book() { Title= "Peter Pan", Description ="Story Book"};
    }
}
```

when I run the project, and go to `https://localhost:7177/api/publicdata/book`
and this one `https://localhost:7177/app` , can also access vite frontend
it can return my data
and then I try change `vite.config.ts` like :

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import mkcert from 'vite-plugin-mkcert'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: '/app',
  server: {
      https: true,
      port: 6363,
      proxy: {
          "/api": {
              target: "https://localhost:7177",
              changeOrigin: true,
              secure: false
          }
      }
  },
  plugins: [react(), mkcert()],
})
```

after that , I try to run
`https://localhost:7177/app/api/publicdata/book`
or
`https://localhost:7177/app/api/api/publicdata/book`
it didn't work,
but try to run front end port `https://localhost:6363/api/publicdata/book` is working

can I know how to make it work in port 7177 ?

Comment: This is how it's intended to work. I assume "https://localhost:7177/app" is serving the app built by ViteJs using your .Net Web App. The ViteJs `server` configuration is for the dev server that ViteJs runs while you are developing your frontend. This server is running on port `6363`. This server contains your proxy settings, not your frontend. TLDR: The proxy settings under `server` in ViteJs are for the ViteJs dev server ONLY (running on port `6363`  from the settings provided). This has no effect on the .Net instance you are running through Kestrel or IIS on 7177.

Comment: Ok thank you , I got it