# Vite on dotnet spa setting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, proxy, single-page-application, vite

I create the project which dotnet spa proxy to vite.js
From the work example :
In the vite.config.ts

```
export default defineConfig({
  // base: '/app',
  server: {
      https: true,
      port: 6363,
  },
  plugins: [react(), mkcert()],
})
```

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{

```
app.MapWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"),
    builder =>
    {
        builder.UseSpa(spa => spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("https://localhost:6363"));
    }
);
```

If I run the dotnet in development mode, it's work as I expect where all path will route to vite (exclude /api)
Then in production environment, I do the same

```
 app.MapWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), client =>
 {
     client.UseSpaStaticFiles();
     client.UseSpa(spa => {
         spa.Options.SourcePath = "clientapp";            
         spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
         {
             OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
             {
                 ResponseHeaders headers = ctx.Context.Response.GetTypedHeaders();
                 headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
                 {
                     NoCache = true,
                     NoStore = true,
                     MustRevalidate = true
                 };
             }
         };
     });
 });
```

When I do publish -c release and then run https://localhost:{dotnet_port} ,  It return error

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: The request reached the end of the pipeline without executing the endpoint
```

and I know the example come from https://blog.codeinside.eu/2023/02/11/aspnet-core-react-with-vitejs/ is work, but I don't want it alway restrict to use https://localhost:{dotnet_port}/app
Can I know how to config it , which I want :
All route exlude /api  will redirect to vite and apply to release environment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vite proxy config on dotnet spa seem not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77301017/vite-proxy-config-on-dotnet-spa-seem-not-working)